# Coffeescript/JQuery/Rails: $.ajax - Parse error, unexpected '{'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I don't manage to get past a simple parser error for quite some time now. I found several code sample on the web and those seem to be similar - I would deeply appreciate a hint!

```
$ ->
  $(".category_modal").click (e) ->
    alert "Hi"
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax 
      url: 'entries/detail'
      type: "GET"  <-- Error: Parse error on line 28: Unexpected '{'
      dataType: 'json'
      success: (data) ->
        alert "Hi again"
        $(".category_modal").html(data)
```

Comment: [Works fine](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24(%22.category_modal%22).click%20(e)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22Hi%22%0A%20%20%20%20e.preventDefault()%0A%20%20%20%20%24.ajax%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20'entries%2Fdetail'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%22GET%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20dataType%3A%20'json'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20success%3A%20(data)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20%22Hi%20again%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24(%22.category_modal%22).html(data)) here.

Comment: @shesek: http://jsfiddle.net/ also supports CS now, look under "Panels" in the sidebar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the IDE you use, I have found out that oftentimes I get errors compiling Coffescript files due to malformed spaces.

Solution: Select all the spaces before 'type:' AND the ones on the end of the previous line, ie after: 'tries/detail'

Delete them, and form them again and try again to compile. This happens especially when I copy-paste from other sources

Comment: So, in other words, you've been missing tabs and spaces. Don't do that. Set your editor to use "soft tabs" so that when you press Tab, you actually get spaces.

Comment: Wow.  This one was freaking irritating as heck!  Thanks for the tip.  Yay for Sublime Text "Convert indentation to spaces"!

Comment: I thank you for helping me finally letting myself to go to bed soon, I have been fighting with a similar issue for more than the past half hour - blaming myself that I don't understand how to properly translate javascript to cofeescript. The fact that you sound greek as well makes this story even cooler. Efharisto! :)

Comment: given that tabs and spaces *look* identical in the editor but don't *work* the same i've since long come to look upon identation-based languages that allow to mix spaces and tabs as flawed—coffeescript and python should loudly complain when given a file that contains a mixture of spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Your excerpt compiles fine while using the online-compiler at http://coffeescript.org/

Comment: ...probably because in the process of copying spaces and tabs got unified.